# matplotlib | Grouped Data Frame Plotting Issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am sure this has been answered at some point, but I cannot seem to hit the right search terms to figure out a solution.  I am trying to plot a series of lines from  a grouped dataframe where the color of the lines aligns with the grouping key on the dataframe.  I am 99% there, but now I am getting an odd output where the final data point of the lines in the plot is reconnected to the origin.  I assume this has to do with the x-axis having different "length" depending on the series being plotted.

￼￼[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYCfS.png)

EDIT: Here is an example of what x and y look like in the grouped data frame:

```
(2013,         team  year  month   x         y   z
Index                                      
665    team2  2013      1   6  0.003268   1
666    team2  2013      1   7  0.003390   1
667    team2  2013      1   8  0.006969   2
668    team2  2013      1   9  0.003571   1
669    team2  2013      1  10  0.011152   3
670    team2  2013      1  11  0.007634   2
671    team2  2013      1  12  0.028226   7
672    team2  2013      1  13  0.016949   4
673    team2  2013      1  14  0.022026   5
674    team2  2013      1  15  0.013761   3
675    team2  2013      1  16  0.023810   5
676    team2  2013      1  18  0.010204   2
677    team2  2013      1  19  0.021858   4
678    team2  2013      1  20  0.034091   6
679    team2  2013      1  21  0.046784   8
680    team2  2013      1  22  0.037975   6
681    team2  2013      1  23  0.020548   3
682    team2  2013      1  24  0.021277   3
683    team2  2013      1  25  0.021277   3
684    team2  2013      1  26  0.007407   1
685    team2  2013      1  27  0.015267   2
686    team2  2013      1  29  0.008130   1
687    team2  2013      1  30  0.016807   2
688    team2  2013      1  31  0.034783   4
689    team2  2013      1  33  0.028302   3
690    team2  2013      1  34  0.019048   2
691    team2  2013      1  35  0.038095   4
692    team2  2013      2   4  0.005405   1
693    team2  2013      2   6  0.016667   3
694    team2  2013      2   7  0.005848   1
     ...   ...    ...  ..       ...  ..
953    team2  2013     11  18  0.045767  20
954    team2  2013     11  19  0.057279  24
955    team2  2013     11  20  0.042079  17
956    team2  2013     11  21  0.027919  11
957    team2  2013     11  22  0.025907  10
958    team2  2013     11  23  0.029650  11
959    team2  2013     11  24  0.032787  12
960    team2  2013     11  25  0.030220  11
961    team2  2013     12   3  0.002621   2
962    team2  2013     12   4  0.006640   5
963    team2  2013     12   5  0.010782   8
964    team2  2013     12   6  0.009602   7
965    team2  2013     12   7  0.008368   6
966    team2  2013     12   8  0.018466  13
967    team2  2013     12   9  0.013043   9
968    team2  2013     12  10  0.019345  13
969    team2  2013     12  11  0.015291  10
970    team2  2013     12  12  0.023364  15
```

---

```
colors = {2013: 'r', 2014: 'b', 2015: 'g'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = []

for key, grp in dqData[dqData['team'] == 'team1'].groupby(['year']):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x='x', y='y', figsize=(10,10), xlim=(0,30), sharex= True,c = colors[key])
    labels.append(key)

lines, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does your data frame look like? Using `kind='line'` will connect consecutive points with a line, so my first guess is that you have trailing (0, 0) points at the end of each.

Comment: Added an example of what the frame looks like.  There are no trailing zeros, but I assume they are some how being created in the plot since x is of different length?

Comment: What does `grp` look like?

Comment: Updated for an actual snapshot of the group.

Comment: Wonder if it would help to pivot / unstack the data?  I'll give that a try.  Seems like a pain to have to do that if it works...

Comment: That would definitely help you narrow down your problem. Also you don't have to pass `figsize` and `sharex` each time in your `for` loop. You can instead pass them to `plt.subplots()` above. You should also only have to set `xlim` once with `ax.set_xlim(0, 30)` since you're putting everything on the same axes.

Comment: Thanks for the notes on sharex, xlim, and figsize.  Makes since to not have to assign more than once.  Pivoting the data on each 'month' in grp worked.  I'll post the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below.  Had to pivot the data and create NaNs.

```
colors = {2013: 'r', 2014: 'b', 2015: 'g'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
labels = []

for key, grp in dqData[dqData['team'] == 'team1'].groupby(['year']):
    g2 = grp.pivot(index='x', columns='month', values='y')
    ax = g2.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', c = colors[key])
    labels.append(key)

lines, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='best')
plt.show()
```